# Letting big shadows bleed between UITableView cells

Tags: swift, uitableview, cell, shadow

I've created a UITableViewCell with a textfield in it, which has a large diffused shadow underneath it.  I've also set it up so that these big shadows can blend under its surrounding cells.

[image]

NB.  Shadow has been HEAVILY emphasised here to show the problem.

The problem is that I want the shadow from my `EMAIL` textfield to blend *underneath* the password cell.  i.e. I want both textfields to have a white background, but underneath them both I have the shadow.  Something like this:

[image]

The reason this is a problem is because the UITableView is being rendered with upper cells "above" the lower ones.  So any shadow from the cell at row 1 will bleed on top of the cells in rows 2, 3, 4 etc.

I was wondering if perhaps there is a way to change this rendering, and instead reverse the rendering so that a cell in row 4 is actually ABOVE rows 3, 2 and 1.

Or perhaps there is a way of setting the Password textfield so that no shadows are rendered on top of it?

Any help, very much appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried changing the `zPosition` property of each cell? Maybe that could help.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Amr for pointing me in the direction of the `cell.layer.zPosition`.

The higher the value this is, the "closer" to the viewer the layer sits, so as long as each row has a higher value, it will appear "above" the shadows from any cells around it.

Since I use multiple sections in my code, I used this line to assign each cell above the previous one.

`cell.layer.zPosition = CGFloat(indexPath.section) * 1000 + CGFloat(indexPath.row)`